# Magento: Add static block in between rows of products in category view

Tags: magento, block, categories, product, php

I have category pages with rows of 4 products and a standard view of 16 products per page (4 rows).

I want my category pages to show a static block under the first row and one other statick block under the third row of products.

Like this:

### ROW 1

### STATIC BLOCK 1

### ROW 2

### ROW 3

### STATIC BLOCK 2

### ROW 4

I think i can do this in the template/catalog/product/list.phtml
but I don't know what code to use en where to put it.

Regards, Rik!

Answer (score 0):

you will find this line of code in  template/catalog/product/list.phtml

This is executed as last statement for each product.

So you place a counter above this and with some if condition place your code in .phtml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about grid view, as Satish said:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml:90
```

`base` and `default` may be different for you, if you are using a theme,

```
<?php $rowCount = 0; ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
      <?php  $rowCount++; ?>
      <?php if ($rowCount == 2 || $rowCount == 4): ?>
         <ul class="awesome-new-row"><li>ok then</li></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
      <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
           <?php //LEFT OUT .. NORMAL CODE HERE ?>
      </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Hi @AKnox, thanks for the quick answer. I'm new to this so could you please explain to me where i should put this in the view.phtml? And do i just call the block with: echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('get_know_toesox')->toHtml() on the place you have //LEFT OUT .. NORMAL CODE HERE ?